# .htaccess and filtering $_GET

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, filter-var

Hello I am writing a profile page script, in this script I check the value of an incoming $_GET variable and validate that it is an integer, I then validate this value against a $_SESSION value to confirm that they can only access their own accounts. The code looks like this:

```
// validate $_GET field 
if(isset($_GET['identity']) && filter_var($_GET['identity'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1))) {


if(isset($_SESSION['user_identity']) && ((int)$_SESSION['user_identity'] === (int)$_GET['identity'])) { // if session exists and is === $_GET['identity']
// Proceed with code
```

This works fine for instance if I try to pass '0','2-2','abc' or no value as the $_GET value the query correctly fails and redirects them to the home page.

What I then tried to do was alter my .htaccess file to map the URLs to 'profile/1' just to tidy it up.

```
RewriteRule ^profile$ profile.php
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)$ profile.php?identity=$1 [NC,L]
```

What I found now is that the page doesn't redirect any more using those invalid $_GET parameters above. It just tries to find 'profile/abc.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use this and it works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^profile$ profile.php
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ profile.php?identity=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Now, how did you get `profile/abc`? if you try to pass letters in the rule it wont work since you only specify numbers `([0-9]+)`. If you want to pass letters you will need to use:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ profile.php?identity=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, I shall try your rules out. I have no idea, it must be something to do with my .htacces rules because the php statements explicitly rule out anything that isn't === an integer and passing the $_GET in the urls unmasked throws everything else out.

Comment: I just tried it, I still get the same result. How strange, maybe it's some quirk in my system. Appreciate your help though

Comment: I have just page specific reWrites currently, I am early in development. They are just removing the trailing .php extension and the one url allows for ^page/sub-category. The .htacces is in my root htdocs folder along with the site itself. To just clarify in my inital post when i said the page now tries to find "profile/abc" it just tries to find any of the bad examples I listed such as "profile/2-2" or "profile/"

Comment: Maybe you have a conflict between rules, can you show the .htaccess?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4294/discussion-between-book-of-zeus-and-jonnny)

Comment: Thanks to the help of Book Of Zeus who a) took the time to find out that the rule should be:
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ profile.php?identity=$1 [NC,L,QSA]